# Asking a question about programming structure

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

I asked a question about programming structure - [Creating a scalable project in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44686095/creating-a-scalable-project-in-visual-studio)

While I agree that it can be somewhat opinion based, I do believe that there are right / wrong answers to it. An issue that I run into a lot on SO, is I know I want to do something, and I know how to write the backend code, but I've been googling things all day, and haven't had a solid answer as to how someone might organize a program, so I come here to ask for input (because isn't that what SO is for?) but it gets closed as too broad. I'm not really sure how I can narrow it down to fit the question requirements. Even so, if it is a little broad, doesn't mean it is an unanswerable question. I am just looking for some guidance as in - "One method you might want to consider is adding each individual project to a global project... etc"

For instance - this is an old question that appears to be protected, yet it seems as though it is asking a similar thing. [How do I add an existing directory tree to a project in Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/392473/how-do-i-add-an-existing-directory-tree-to-a-project-in-visual-studio)

Is that just because the rules have changed over the years or has the mentality of people willing to help changed?

How can I better structure this question?

Comment: If someone posts an answer how could you possibly argue that it's wrong (or right)?  You're most certainly asking for opinions, in addition to it being very broad as a question.

Comment: No, SO is not here to give you opinions on your program.  It's here to be a reference source for programming questions that will be applicable to a wide audience.

Comment: `Even so, if it is a little broad, doesn't mean it is an unanswerable question` That's *exactly* what that means...

Comment: @Servy incorrect. Every question is answerable, even a broad one. And most questions have multiple answers. SO is also absolutely here to give opinions on programs. Every time I ask a question regarding a piece of code a person comes back with their opinion of how it can look and function, and every piece of code can be written in multiple ways. That I strongly believe is a programming question and can be applicable to a wide audience that might want to look into creating a similar program.

Comment: Define _similar_. This is only useful to you. No one will every find your question and make use of any answers. That alone makes it useless to Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Adjit By "answerable" I mean, "given a good answer that meets the site's quality standards" and not "is able to post some text in the answer box, even if it's not actually a good answer".  A broad answer may technically be answerable with a book, but it's not answerable *in an SO answer*.  That you personally want to get opinions and don't *care* that the question is primarily opinion based doesn't make it not opinion based; in fact, it makes it the opposite.  That you want opinions doesn't mean that your question isn't opinion based.

Comment: "SO is also absolutely here to give opinions on programs." - No it isn't. "Every time I ask a question regarding a piece of code a person comes back with their opinion of how it can look and function" - That still doesn't mean that this kind of question is on-topic, some people just prefer to care more about their reputation (i.e. answering such questions) instead of closing them.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis and this question asking for debugging help specific to their situation makes it useful to who? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39253622/javascript-code-not-working-after-several-attempts/39253924

Comment: @Servy reference my comment above - how does that question help anyone else on SO aside from the user who asked the question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39253622/javascript-code-not-working-after-several-attempts/39253924

Comment: @Adjit No one. "Javascript code not working after several attempts" is a terrible question.

Comment: @Adjit If you feel that a given question isn't going to be useful to others then by all means *reflect that opinion with your vote*.  Additionally, many questions like this are problematic simply due to poor phrasing.  A question that does a good job of describing the problem, rather than just dumping code with an "it doesn't work" can often mean that it *is* a good canonical resource for how to solve that particular problem.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis not necessarily according to SO. This person posted a piece of their code that wasn't working and SO helped that person out. I think that is a good question for SO, but the question title is definitely broad.

Comment: @Adjit The fact that people answer bad questions that don't belong on SO doesn't mean that those questions are up to the site's standards, it just means that many people choose to disregard the site's standards (or at least some of them).

Comment: Your question is way too broad.  Entire books can been written on the subject and they won't even cover it all.

Comment: @Servy but how on earth would anyone with that persons specific issue ever come across that question? And why should I deny a person the ability to have a question answered? They may be a poor question asker, so I might make an assumption about what the answer might be and move on. I see SO as more of an open forum for question asking. At least that is what it used to be. Now I feel that people, more often than not, vote to close than to try and help a person out. But, I do agree that SO has A LOT of bad questions. Personally, I don't think this was one of them

Comment: @Servy especially because if you look at a lot of old protected questions, you will see they too do seem like they are broad questions that cannot be answered.

Comment: At what point does SO reach a completed repository? Do we intend to close the site off to all future questions at that point because every bit of information on a tag has already been provided if you are intelligent enough to know what you're looking for?

Comment: @SandPiper but that's the thing. At this point in time a lot of duplicate questions have answers from 4/5 years ago. Sure a lot of that stuff can stay the same. But in many cases there can be a new answer more applicable to the times

Comment: @Adjit To be clear, I'm mostly with you in principle, however in this case architecture questions are specifically outside of the scope of SO. It's not that they are invalid questions, this is just not the particular site for them. On the topic of site standards, I believe many in this community are focusing on the WHAT of StackOverflow (i.e. "Provide a repository of user knowledge on all programming topics") and are losing site of the WHY (i.e. "To help programmers get unstuck on problems they have been bashing their heads in over for days").

Comment: "i see SO as more of an open forum for question asking" then there is a fundamental part of the site's goal you have completely misunderstood :/

Comment: @Patrice not true at all. The sites goals have changed over the years. Not for better imo. Questions that were ok 5 years ago are no longer ok. Old protected questions that I come across all the time are very broad that would be closed in a heartbeat today. I'm not trying to defend my question anymore, just challenging the reasons people close questions

Comment: @SandPiper SO isn't ever going to be completed, there will always be more useful information that can be added, both because new technologies are always coming out, and because there is simply *so much* useful information out there to hold that there's no practical way to ever have it all.  It does however get increasing harder to ask good questions in older topics that aren't changing/innovating.

Comment: @Adjit There have been *very* few changes to what's acceptable here over the years, and almost all of the big changes happened over the course of the first few months up to a year or two.  There have not been a lot of changes to the site's scope/topic since like 2010, and most of the changes that there have been have been *very* small.   You're simply coming across older questions *that didn't belong here even when they were first posted* that simply didn't get closed *despite meriting it*.  There have always been insufficient people using their close votes to close the posts that need it.

Comment: @Servy But has anyone actually read what SO has to say about Subjective questions? https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/09/29/good-subjective-bad-subjective/ - Because if they did, I feel as though this question would not have been closed. Yes, it could've used a little better outlining and explaining, but not a reason to close, maybe just needed a tad more guidance

Comment: @Adjit I'm well aware of the blog post.  I still stand by the statement that that question is way too subjective for SO.  The subjectiveness may not be a problem for other sites (keep in mind that that blog post was created to be used with newer SE sites that were designed to have more subjective topics, unlike SO which is centered around objective questions).  The question also has numerous other problems, such as being Too Broad, being unclear, and lacking sufficient information.

Comment: @Adjit Note that when a question isn't acceptable the appropriate course of action is to close it.  This gives the author the opportunity to fix the question and correct the problems with it.  If you are able to fix the problems with it, it can be reopened.  We don't leave close-worthy quesitons open for a while to see if the author ends up fixing them.

Comment: @Servy I'm not sure why you think a blog post on SO is meant for other sites, and the rules of SO link directly to that. I don't think the question was unclear - I expressed what my objective was. Lacking sufficient information in what regards? Too broad - maybe, but I think the main issue is the mentality behind the close. It's not as if there wasn't enough information there for someone to give an input as for as program structure. Normally, I would post something like - I might try x, but there is no way of knowing unless you clarify y.

Comment: @Servy and so you automatically close a question without telling the user what they could do to make the question more applicable? Isn't this site supposed to be constructive? Just closing questions is unconstructive without providing any guidance. How are you supposed to educate the community?

Comment: @Adjit You can read the beginning of the blog post for an explanation of that.  It specifically mentions that SO is about objective questions, but that other sites have had both good and bad luck with subjective questions, so the blog post is discussing that, to better explain how the more subjective sites can improve the quality of their questions.  That you think your question is clear doesn't really mean it's clear to *others*  You of course know more about what you want to know than you've written down.

Comment: When your question is closed you're given the close reason, and it has lots of info in the help center on how those issues can be addressed.  Users are of course more than welcome to add additional information if they would like to, in your case I don't see how the question is salvageable, so I know if I saw it I wouldn't see much point in commenting as I don't see how the question could possibly be made to be appropriate.

Comment: @Servy I can agree with you to an extent about the question being unsalvagable, but if you look at what questions to avoid asking it says subjective questions are allowed [here] but they have to follow the guideline. IMO, I definitely think this question is constructive - how could someone structure an application that utilizes standalone programs. I can also see how that gets very broad very quickly, but I had specific requirements that I outlined.

Comment: @Adjit You had some requirements, they're certainly not specific, and there is no criteria by which you can determine whether an answer is "correct" or not.  Again, you've stated that you're looking for *opinions*, and that's exactly what we don't want here.  While there can be some level of subjectivity that's acceptable, this is *well* past that point, as it really is just asking for opinions, and nothing else.

Answer (score 10):

The instant you realize that there's an opinion on this to be had, an argument can be made for it to be off-topic on Stack Overflow.

We don't deal in project design, which is what you're asking about.  We're looking to provide concrete answers to questions instead of suppositions.

Your question *might* fare better on Software Engineering, but do [check what they will and won't answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) before reposting it.

Comment: probably more focused guidance is on SE.SE meta: [What goes on Software Engineering (previously known as Programmers)? A guide for Stack Overflow](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7182/31260)